# Graphing $f$ from $f'$ (anti derivative) if $f'$ is an ECG curve

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I was interested in the anti derivative of an ECG curve. The idea was electromagnetic induction occurs when current changes, and that what ECG might be reading is the derivative, the rate of change, of electrical activity in the heart. The assumption (ECG is rate of change) might be wrong, but an antiderivative can still be drawn in that case, so if anyone wants to help me out with that regardless of if the "why" is sound, it is welcome. I thought I'd ask here since there might be many people who are good at anti-derivatives. This is actually a pretty interesting question, that has not been asked or explored that many times.

[Attached image of a generic ECG curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDfGm.png)

[This was my own best attempt so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upynS.png)

Comment: Just graph a function representing the signed area under the curve (up to a constant vertical shift): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDbIeNhX6vE

Comment: I've done some attempts simultaneous with asking here (I only ask as my own attempts are likely not as good as someone who has experience), and I attached the results of that.

Comment: If you have some numbers on the graph, you can make a more precise sketch. But it might be better to practice with simpler examples first, such as the one in the youtube clip

Comment: My question is not how to best practice on antiderivatives, but what the antiderivative of an ECG would look like. I'm not retarded, I can understand that I can practice antiderivatives, or any other skill. But, the only point to have a Q&A forum is when people prefer to ask, instead of do the work themselves. Of course. I mean, obviously. It is literally the only reason.

Comment: Perhaps I meant to say it would be better to work on more *precise* examples. The fact of the matter is it is impossible to sketch an antiderivative of the *particular* graph you attached since it lacks numerical information. To take an extreme case, if that graph showed only negative (resp. positive) values, then any antiderivative would be strictly decreasing (resp. increasing).

Comment: Also, in my first response, I addressed how to sketch an antiderivative of virtually *any* function you can think of, ECG-related or not...